# Can't convert 'str' to numerical value in Python 3.0

Tags: python, string, integer, multiple-columns, numeric

I am a new python coder so bare with me. I want to convert certain columns from 'str' to 'int' or 'float'. However, no matter what code I apply to the columns (pd.to_numerical, astype(int) etc), it always gives me errors or the numbers are still showing as 'str'. This is an example of the type of I code I want to use:

```
data = pd.read_csv('...xyz')

cols = data.columns[7:13]
for i in cols:
data[i] = data[i].str.strip()
data[i] = data[i].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerse').fillna(0) -->This code gives me "ValueError: invalid error value specified"

data[i] = data[i].astype('float64') -->This code gives me "ValueError: could not convert string to float: '77,830'"

data[i] = data[i].astype(int) -->This code gives me "ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer"
```

At first, I thought it was an issue with white spaces in the numbers but even when I strip them, the issue remains. What am I missing??? Any advice will be appreciated!

Comment: For the 2nd line, you need to remove the comma in your string before converting that to a float.

Comment: 1st attempt, you misspelled 'coerce' in the `errors` argument. 2nd, you need to remove the comma. The third, you need to check for NaN values beforehand or include the `errors` argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers all! They defo guided me to the solution.
What I ended up doing is

```
data = pd.read_csv('...xyz', thousands=',')
```

Funnily enough that fixed 2 of the 4 columns I wanted fixed because it didn't recognise the comma as thousands. For the rest I did the below:

```
cols = data.columns[8:10]

for i in cols:
    data[i] = data[i].str.replace(',','')
    data[i] = data[i].str.strip()
    data[i] = data[i].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').fillna(0)
```

The 'astype' didn't work here either, so I had to do 'pd.to_numeric'.

Answer (score 0):

In the first try, the `errors='coerse'` should be `errors='coerce'`. The others are likely failing as the numeric string has commas in it.